# (iphone) am I creating a leak when creating a new image from an image?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, retain

I have following code as UIImage+Scale.h category.

```
-(UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size
{                                                                                                                                                                                     
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

  [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

  // is this scaledImage auto-released?                                                                                                                                                                                        
  UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return scaledImage;
}
```

I use image obtained as above and use it as following.

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: myData];
image = [image scaleToSize: size]; <- wouldn't this code create a leak since
                                    image(before scaling) is lost somewhere?
```

i guess above codes work fine if image was first created with auto-release.
But if image was created using 'alloc', it would create a leak in my short knowledge.

How should I change scaleToSize: to guard against it?

Thank you

- EDIT -

I'd like to use alloc(or retain)/release on UIImage so that I can keep the # of UIImage in memory at a point small.
(i'm loading many UIImages in a loop and device can't take it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your code could be rewritten as:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
UIImage *scaledImage = [image scaleToSize:size];
image = scaledImage;
```

so let’s see what happens:

- `image` is obtained via `alloc`, hence you own that object
- `scaledImage` is obtained via a method that returns an autoreleased object since `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns an autoreleased object
- you own the original `image` but you don’t own `scaledImage`. You are responsible for releasing the original `image`, otherwise you have a leak.

In your code, you use a single variable to refer to both objects: the original image and the scaled image. This doesn’t change the fact that you *own* the first image, hence you need to release it to avoid leaks. Since you lose the original image reference by using the same variable, one common idiom is to send `-autorelease` to the original object:

```
UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData] autorelease];
image = [image scaleToSize:size];
```

Or, if you’d rather release the original image instead of autoreleasing it,

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
UIImage *scaledImage = [image scaleToSize:size];
[image release];
// use scaledImage from this point on, or assign image = scaledImage
```

IMO, it doesn’t make sense to change `scaleToSize:`. It is an instance method that creates an (autoreleased) image based on a given `UIImage` instance. It’s similar to `-[NSString stringByAppendingString:]`, which creates a (an autoreleased) string based on a given `NSString` instance. It doesn’t and shouldn’t care about the ownership of the original string, and the same applies to your `scaleToSize:` method. How would the method know whether the caller wants to keep the original image?

I’d also rename `scaleToSize:` to `imageByScalingToSize` to make it similar to Cocoa’s naming convention — you’re getting an image by applying an operation to an existing image.

Comment: Since when i modify image, most of time, I want to change the image itself, not creating a new one. I was hoping to change scaleToSize: . I recently realized that UIImage is rather big memory consumer and want to keep the number of UIImage* in memory small. or at least, use alloc/release instead of autorelease.

Comment: `UIImage` is immutable. You can’t simply change it. And, except if you’re creating many images at once, using an autorelease pool won’t be much different then sending `-release` manually. I’ll update the post to tell you how to use `-release` instead of `-autorelease`.

Comment: Thanks Bavarious, yes I 'm creating many images at once and want to handle memory release myself.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using alloc/release & creating autorelease pool/realeasing pool when necessary based on your suggestion. info on UIImage being immutable helped a great deal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is sure that you have a leak. The object stored previously in the image is not referenced anymore but not deallocated yet